# webpack cli menu for setting configuration

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I see in the vue-cli setup something like this ([meta.js](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/blob/fd65d24ad2ed5113dfb6790c600c51e6ea572cd8/meta.js))

```
user@ny-laptop ~/Documents/
> $ vue init webpack my-project                                                                                          

? Project name hi
? Project description how do i get this menu?
? Author (user <user@gmail.com>)
...etc
```

How does one go about creating a menu based configuration like this for a new webpack project? I have a core template that will have a lot of options, being able to select ahead of time would be very helpful.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it by adding properties to the [`meta.js`](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/blob/1.3.1/meta.js#L47).

## Step by step example:

- Fork https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack

  - Example: https://github.com/acdcjunior/webpack-vue-template (besides forking I have renamed the repo as well)
- IMPORTANT: Make sure you are at **`master` branch** and commit.

  - [Edit the `meta.js` file](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/blob/1.3.1/meta.js#L47), adding properties.
  - For example, I have added the `weather` question: [**commit here**.](https://github.com/acdcjunior/webpack-vue-template/commit/4a762196b0164183f65f951f3992a1078631168c)
- Now use `vue init`

  - Example:

    ```
    vue init acdcjunior/webpack-vue-template my-project-from-my-template
    ```

Example output (notice **second question**):

```
$ vue init acdcjunior/webpack-vue-template my-project-from-my-template

? Project name my-project-from-my-template
? How's the weather today? Very nice, thanks.
? Project description A Vue.js project template by acdcjunior
...
```

The created properties can be used in the templates:

- See [`/template` folder](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/tree/1.3.1/template).
- Example:

  - [`lintConfig` in meta.js](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/blob/1.3.1/meta.js#L82)
  - Is [used in `package.json`'s tempalte to set some `dependencies`](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/blob/1.3.1/template/package.json).

This is valid for [Vue-cli v2.x](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/tree/v2.9.3).